# notification received but data is not updated to iphone

Tags: spring, hibernate

i'm using restful web service. In that i have a method, by using this method i send notification and mails. My method is working fine, only problem is that notification pops up 2,3 seconds before you get success response after calling this method.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public MedikmResponse createNPostCcbrQuestion(CreateNPostCcbrQuestionRequest createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest, HttpServletRequest request) {
     logger.info("#########################Post Ccbr Question#############################"); 
     MedikmResponse medikmResponse=new MedikmResponse();
      try {
            String token =   request.getHeader("authToken");
            User user = userDao.findUserByAuthToken(token);
             if (user != null) {
                   /**
                    * Question Creation 
                    */
                    CcbrQuestion ccbrQuestion=new CcbrQuestion(); 
                    ccbrQuestion.setQuestiomtext(createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getCcbrQuestionText());
                    Integer questionId=ccbrQuestionDao.saveCcbrQuestion(ccbrQuestion); 
                    ccbrQuestion.setQuestionId(questionId);
                   /* ***
                     * Question post
                     */
                    TbDiscussionForumQuestion tbDiscussionForumQuestion=new TbDiscussionForumQuestion();
                    tbDiscussionForumQuestion.setCCBRQuestionId(ccbrQuestion);
                    tbDiscussionForumQuestion.setTBDiscussionId(new TbDiscussionForum(createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getTbdiscussionId()));
                    tbDiscussionForumQuestion.setPhysicianId(new Physician(user.getPhysicianId().getPhysicianId()));
                    tbDiscussionForumQuestion.setQuestion(createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getCcbrQuestionText());
                    tbDiscussionForumQuestion.setQuestionDate(new Date());
                    //tbDiscussionForumQuestionDao.saveTbDiscussionForumQuestion(tbDiscussionForumQuestion);

                    TbDiscussionForum discussionForum=tbDiscussionForumDao.findTbDiscussionForumbyTbId(createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getTbdiscussionId());
                    discussionForum.getTbDiscussionForumQuestionCollection().add(tbDiscussionForumQuestion);
                    tbDiscussionForumDao.updateTbDiscussionForum(discussionForum);
                    String[] deviceIdList=getParticpentDeviceIdList(discussionForum.getCaseId().getCaseId(), user);
                    medikmResponse.setAuthenticationKey(user.getAuthToken());
                    notificationSender.sendPostedCcbrQuestionToVMDCParticipant(discussionForum.getCaseId(), user.getPhysicianId(), createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getCcbrQuestionText());//sending mail
                    if(deviceIdList.length!=0){
                        notificationService.sendNotificationToIOS(deviceIdList,discussionForum.getCaseId().getCaseId(),createNPostCcbrQuestionRequest.getTbdiscussionId(),"Question");
                     }
                    medikmResponse.setResponseCode(MedikmConstants.SUCCESS_CODE);
                    medikmResponse.setResponseMessage(MedikmConstants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE);

             }else{

                  medikmResponse.setResponseCode(MedikmConstants.FAILURE_CODE);
                  medikmResponse.setResponseMessage(MedikmConstants.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
                  logger.info("############ USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST  #############"+ MedikmConstants.USER_DOES_NOT_EXIST);
           }
           return medikmResponse;
      }catch(Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
    } 
}
```

Comment: you havent posted what you , actually want to do . i suppose that sendNotificationToIOS might add overhead to the whole process as well as it might cause an exception, but in case the sendNotificationToIOS fails , you will still want to send SUCCESS_CODE at the restful service response ? if it doesn't affect the response , then the proposed solution you posted might fit your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for this i add @Async annotation in the sendNotificationToIOS method and it works for me after adding  this annotation need to add   in your xml